# comparing each value in a dictionary to each other value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a python code that would compare each value in a dictionary to each other value. For example:

```
dict={key1:[values1],key2:[values2],key3:[values3}.
```

I would like to compare each value with each other value. i.e. `value1` with `value2`, `value1` with `value3`,  `value2` with `value3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what your looking for?

```
for k in topology:
    for j in topology:
        if k == j:
            continue
        else:
            # compare values at key k and key j
            my_compare_function(topology[k], topology[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to create all pairs. Here is a trivial example:

```
from itertools import combinations
# create an example dictionary
dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2}
# generate all pairs
all_pairs = list(combinations(dict.items(), r = 2))
# create mapping of comparisons of the values of each pair
{pair:pair[0][1] == pair[1][1] for pair in all_pairs}
```

Output:

```
(('c', 2), ('b', 2)): True, (('a', 1), ('b', 2)): False, (('a', 1), ('c', 2)): False}
```